# Stray CSS in et-divi-customizer-global-cached-inline-style

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, divi

I've got some CSS that I can't find which is in et-divi-customizer-global-cached-inline-style, its not in the custom CSS in Divi and I can't find it in the database.

I haven't added any custom css files

Looking for suggestions as to where else it might be located

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?  I have the same issue and it's causing some customizer controls not to function (because the cached inline CSS is overriding the CSS from the customizer one would assume)...

Answer (score 1):

Don't have a solution yet, but I have the same problem.

I think it is generated CSS with the customizer settings. Which then is outputted in the head see output example

[image]

The css is part of `<style id="et-divi-customizer-global-cached-inline-styles">`

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago this answer. But I had the same problem, but it seems that CSS placed there (on the bottom of the page) is taken from the DIVI modules. So check which module 'behaves' strange and search in the design tab what behaviour you have to change.

Hope this helps. It seems it cannot directly be edited